# Output of System.out.println(-1) will be Integer or String?

Tags: java

When we write:

```
System.out.println(-1);
```

Does Java consider `-1` as `Integer` or `String`?

Comment: Why would that be a string?

Comment: An integer. Of course.

Comment: It's an integer when you call [`println(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(int)). It gets converted to a string in order to print it out.

Comment: Read something about Overloading

Answer (score 4):

If you follow the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(int)), you find:

> public void println(int x)
>
> Prints an integer and then terminate the line. This method behaves as though it invokes `print(int)` and then `println()`.

Then the [`print(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print(int)) documentation says:

> The string produced by `String.valueOf(int`) is translated into bytes according to the platform's default character encoding, and these bytes are written in exactly the manner of the `write(int)` method.

So it converts the integer to a String before converting that to bytes and printing it out.

Answer (score 3):

> Does Java consider -1 as Integer or String?

Neither. `-1` is a primitive `int` literal.

Why is `-1` a primitive int literal?

> int: By default, the int data type is a 32-bit signed two's complement integer, which has a minimum value of -2<sup>31</sup> and a maximum value of 2<sup>31</sup>-1.

Also:

> Integer literals can be expressed by these number systems:
>
> - Decimal: Base 10, whose digits consists of the numbers 0 through 9; this is the number system you use every day
> - Hexadecimal: Base 16, whose digits consist of the numbers 0 through 9 and the letters A through F
> - Binary: Base 2, whose digits consists of the numbers 0 and 1 (you can create binary literals in Java SE 7 and later)

See [Primitive Data Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Comment: a little more context into why -1 is a primitive would be nice, just to show that it is limited to a very small subset of numbers. (to assuage confusion on whether it is negatives, or all numbers...)

Comment: Your edit is much better:) now i like the answer a lot more.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println()): `System.out.println` can accept a lot of parameters, and since you're passing `-1` and this has `int` type, then the method called in your case is `public void println(int x)`.

Behind the scenes though, the `-1` is converted into `String` then into the bytes representation, according to your platform's default character encoding before being sent to the console.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, to be technical- it is neither. Integer is specific to an Integer object in java (As in `ArrayList<Integer>`) An Integer object is not the same as an int. **Your print statement considers the argument as an int.**

```
ArrayList<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<Integer> ();
integers.add(FooIntegerObject);
System.out.print(-1); //is an int
System.out.print("-1"); //is a String
System.out.print(integers(0).toString()); //is an Integer
```